# Android communicating from Service to Clients

Tags: android, android-service, android-service-binding, android-binder

I'd like to keep a reference to each client that binds to a started & bound Android service.  My service is NOT in a separate process.

I can have multiple clients bound, e.g. - 1 Activity and 2 Fragments. They may all be interested in a combination of different events returning from the Service.  Ideally, I'd like to register each client with the Service when they bind and then iterate over each connected client and send them each the message.

Right now I am using the Binder to expose the Service's API to the client, but I am not happy using Broadcasts to send the data from the Service back to the clients.  It feels so "loose". Wondering if there was a more concise & structured way of doing so ?

Message Handler is one way, but I feel like I will lose the binder API the clients are currently accessing the service API through.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **Bound Service** approach detailed [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services#Binder) is appropriate. You don't have to worry about `Handlers`, or even `Intents` (once the client is bound).

Referring to the example at the given link: You can simply add functionality on to the `LocalService` object, e.g.,

```
/** method for clients */
public int getRandomNumber() {
  return mGenerator.nextInt(100);
}

private Set<MyEventListener> mListeners = new HashSet<>();

/** A MyEventListener (your Activity, Fragment, etc.) calls this in its
 * onServiceConnected() method, on the reference it gets from getService(). */
public void registerListener(MyEventListener listener)
{
    mListeners.add(listener);
}

public void sendEvent()
{
    for(MyEventListener listener : mListeners)
    {
         listener.onEvent();
    }
}
```

...and so forth. All methods execute synchronously, on the UI thread. All objects (`Services` and clients (`MyEventListener`)) are guaranteed to have a lifetime at least as long as the `ServiceConnection`. Also, the `ServiceConnection` will not experience an `onServiceDisconnected()` call until you explicitly unbind, since you're using an in-process service.

Comment: I did think about this, but then I felt I will need another method to 'removeListener()'.  And, really didn't want each client to have to worry about that.  My service can get filled with listeners that are no longer alive since this is a long running service.  How can I handle that ?

Comment: You should go into more detail about your objection to a `removeListener()` method. If the `Service` is going to be made aware when a client leaves, something will have to tell it. If code re-use is a concern, then maybe you should consider making a `Fragment`/`Activity` subclass that automatically binds to the service and manages the listener lifecycle.

Comment: The reasoning is just that any other developer binding to the service & registering their listener will have to inherently know that they will need to unregister it as well.

Comment: If you are talking about 3rd party clients in a different process, this won't work.

Comment: Once again, a properly written subclass could enforce these lifecycle rules. But if that really is unreasonable for your use case, you could just use weak references. See: [Observer pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern#Strong_vs._Weak_reference).